# Создание массива динамической структуры Си

Tags: c, массивы, структуры

Что я делаю не так?
Вот код, но он не работает

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
char trash[50];
int dyn_sala_id=1;
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char number[6];
    int persons;
    char tech_inf[256];
} sala;
sala *sala_;

int add_sala()
{
    int persons;
    char number[6], tech_inf[256];


    sala_ = (sala*)realloc(sala_,dyn_sala_id * sizeof(sala));

    printf("Wpisz numer sali(max. 5 znakow): ");
    fgets(number,6,stdin);
    if(strlen(number)>5)
    {
        printf("Numer musi byc nie wiecej, niz 5 znakow!\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        add_sala();
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Wpisz ilosc osob, ktora wmiesci sie w sale(max. 1000 osob): ");
    scanf("%d", &persons);
    if(persons==0 || persons>1000)
    {
        printf("Nie wolno wprowadzic litery oraz max. ilosc osob to 1000\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        add_sala();
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Wpisz info o wyposazeniu sali(max. 255 znakow): ");
    fgets(trash,50,stdin);
    fgets(tech_inf,256,stdin);
    if(strlen(tech_inf)>255)
    {
        printf("Info musi byc nie wiecej, niz 255 znakow!\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        add_sala();
        return 0;
    }

    sala_[dyn_sala_id].id = dyn_sala_id;
    strncpy(sala_[dyn_sala_id].number, number, 6);
    sala_[dyn_sala_id].persons = persons;
    strncpy(sala_[dyn_sala_id].tech_inf, tech_inf, 256);
    printf("\nSala zostala dodana!\n\n");
    printf("%d, %d, %s, %s",dyn_sala_id, persons, number, tech_inf);
    dyn_sala_id+=1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    add_sala();
    printf("%s",sala_[1].number);
    add_sala();
    printf("'%s'",sala_[1].number);
    printf("'%s'",sala_[2].number);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что в этом предложении

```
sala_ = (sala*)malloc(sizeof(sala_));
                             ^^^^^
```

вы имели в виду

```
sala_ = (sala*)malloc(sizeof(sala));
                             ^^^^^
```

Данный цикл

```
while(sala_[sala_id].id!=0)
```

имеет неопределенное поведение. Во-первых, как это было указано выше, вы неправильно выделили память. Во-вторых, значение 1 для переменной `sala_id`

```
int persons, sala_id=1;
             ^^^^^^^^^
```

изначально задано неверно, так как если бы вы даже правильно выделили память для одной структуры, то ее индекс должен быть равен 0, а не 1.

И кроме того, опять-таки, если бы вы правильно выделили память для структуры, тем не менее вы не инициализировали ее поля. Поэтому обращение к полю `id` в любом случае веден к неопределенному поведению программы.

Имейте в виду, что использование функции `scanf` с данной форматной строкой

```
scanf("%s",number);
      ^^^^
```

является опасным и может привести к выходы за пределы массива `number`. Поэтому данная проверка

```
if(strlen(number)>5)
```

просто не имеет никакого смысла и, опять-таки, ведет к неопределенному поведению программы. Лучше использовать стандартную функцию `fgets` в таких случаях.

У вас вся реализация функции `add_sala` некорректная, имеет неопределенное поведение, пытается обращаться к памяти за пределы выделенной памяти и содержит другие баги. Вам следует ее переписать целиком.

Comment: изменил, однако все равно не работает

Comment: Измененный код поменял в шапке

Comment: @MaxPan Не следует менять вопросы. Это вводит в заблуждение тех, кто будет читать вопрос и ответы, так как будет расхождение между ними. На ваш исходный вопрос был дан ответ. Если у вас появились новые вопросы, или изменилась ситуация с кодом, то задавайте отдельные вопросы.